# laptop battery longevity / fear of burn out

Tags: power, batteries, laptop

i have asus t100ha, that i use it 24h a day, or better said i wish that icould, since my partner unplugs it due to extreme energy consumption fear.

now the laptop has 2 lipo batteries, each being 3.6v 7000mAh ( flat battery) about 30wh.

now i was thinking:

1. What if i use some of the cell batteries that i have.

   **problem / Ideea its** they are 3.7v 3000mAh each so if i connect some of them to the existing outputs of the current battery and i boost the battery capacity from 7000mAh to 14000mAh or more , it may just hold the laptop on for up to 12 hours
2. Remove the current batteries and replace with a load of the cells (aspect its not priority )
3. the charger for the laptop gives out 5-9v and 2Ah, so if i place 2 cells together i get 7-8v but i get 3 amps and i lose a lot of power, and on top of that to utilize long longevity i need to hump up the amps, that its why this is third option, because it seems a bit too risky. i do not what to damage the motherboard.

any other idea

Comment: This question is impossible to read.

Comment: sorry , maybe someone else that understands non technical questions

Comment: Building your own laptop battery as an amateur is likely to end in disaster.

Comment: Electrical advice: Plug in the charger when the battery is at 50%. Then, if you remember, unplug it when they are at 75% (or 100% if you forget). Life advice: Try not to worry too much about small things.

Comment: Extra advise: Try not to worry about things you do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries will not change the power consumption of your PC. When you recharge the batteries, they will consume the same (if not more) power. It's pointless, other than to charge the batteries when your partner is not looking so that you can fool them into THINKING you are not consuming the energy...

Comment: The only time energy is being wasted is when the charger is plugged in, and the batteries are full, and the laptop is off. In that scenario, it would be better to unplug the charger.

Comment: thank you everyone , this one its going to be a fail ideea